# Magento load checkout/cart from the quoteId : indexAction()

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.3, magento1.9.2.4

```
if(isset($quoteId) && $quoteId!="" && is_numeric($quoteId)){
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuote($quote);
    Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setQuote($quote);
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->setQuote($quote)->getQuote();
} else {
    $cart = $this->_getCart();
}

if ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
    $cart->init();
    $cart->save();
    if (!$this->_getQuote()->validateMinimumAmount()) {
        $minimumAmount = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())
            ->toCurrency(Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount'));
        $warning = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/description')
            ? Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/description')
            : Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Minimum order amount is %s', $minimumAmount);
        $cart->getCheckoutSession()->addNotice($warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getItemsCount() on null in Checkout/controllers/CartController.php:28

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code this works for me:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
         $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getItemsCount()

Comment: You have use getQuote() on $cart and also $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount(). Remove the getQuote() from second line.

Comment: if(isset($quoteId) && $quoteId!="" && is_numeric($quoteId)){
            
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
            $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();             
            $cart = $this->_getCart();
           
        }
        else{
            $cart = $this->_getCart();
        } 
        if ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) { }